# Opanlayers Reprojection Kml layer

Tags: kml, openlayers, map-projections

I have a map with  'EPSG:32639' projection for base map and 'EPSG:4326' projection for kml layer that show on base map. It just show my basemap and do not show any kml layer. what's wrong with that?

My source code is ther.

```
function initMap(){
            // if this is just a coverage or a group of them, disable a few items,
            // and default to jpeg format
            format = 'image/png';

            var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds(
                551438.385, 3602649.973,
                571430.791, 3627258.571
            );
            var options = {
                controls: [
                                            new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation( {mouseWheelOptions: {interval: 100}}),
                    new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),
                                            new OpenLayers.Control.NavToolbar(),
                    new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher({'ascending':false}),
                    new OpenLayers.Control.Permalink(),
                    new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine(),
                    new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition(),
                                            new OpenLayers.Control.Scale($('scale')),
                                            new OpenLayers.Control.OverviewMap(),
                    new OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults(),
                                            new OpenLayers.Control.ZoomBox({alwaysZoom:true})
                                            ],
                maxExtent: bounds,
                projection: 'EPSG:32639',
                units: 'm',
                                    maxResolution: 136.21203906250003,
                                    numZoomLevels: 10,
            };
            map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', options);


            tiled = new OpenLayers.Layer.TileCache('ESFAHANMAP',
             ['http://www.memap.ir/map'],'ESFAHANMAP',{'format':'image/jpeg',sphericalMercator: true, buffer: 0 });


                            kmlLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('Points', 'point.kml',{
                                    projection: new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326')
                            });
                            map.addLayers([tiled,kmlLayer]);
            map.zoomToExtent(bounds);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't show different projections on the same map. You need to reproject features from your KML to the same projection that you basemap has. See the example [here](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.10/examples/wfs-reprojection.html)